# can't retrieve background image CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having problem with CSS retrieving the pictures to display, but it works on my first form which I use CSS, but the thing is when I created the second CSS and apply on different pages, my background images can't be display and I confirmed that my pictures locations are correct.May I know what kind of issues that might be causing this??

```
<head runat="server">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="studymain.css" type="text/css">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .style2
    {
        font-size: 50pt;
    }
</style>
</link>
```

================================================
below are my studymain.css files

```
body {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment:absolute;
    width:100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('images/Login.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem will be in this line: `url('images/Login.jpg');`.  Your page is probably not where you think it is.

You can try one or more of these fixes:

- Adding a leading slash: `url('/images/Login.jpg');` which tells the server to start looking at the root directory
- Adding a parent directory: `url('../images/Login.jpg');`  which tells the server to look above the current directory (can have more than one of these)
- If it's a Linux server, addresses are case-sensitive, so you may need to use `login.jpg`.
- Make sure the image exists.
- When you view the page source, most browsers will have a link to the image.  Try clicking it to check if the browser can be directed to the image.